# Отправка письма в telegram

Tags: php, telegram

Подскажите, кто нибудь сталкивался в отправкой письма с помощью php в телеграмм конкретному статичному пользователю?

Намекните хоть как идти? API у них чет не особое.

Comment: Бот [не может инициировать беседу](https://core.telegram.org/bots): только отвечать.

Answer (score 4):

> Как идти

Сначала [сюда](https://core.telegram.org/bots) (на англ.). Описано что такое боты, зачем и как написать.

Затем следуете инструкции:

1. в Телеграме начните диалог с ботом `BotFather` – командой /newbot создадите нового бота и получите для него токен;
2. [Получаете сообщения](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates) для вашего бота одним из двух способов:

   - сами периодически запрашиваете обновления у Телеграма для вашего бота («Эй, есть новые сообщения?»);
   - указываете Телеграму URL, по которому тот сам будет к вам стучать, как только получит сообщение для вашего бота.
3. Получив сообщение от пользователя, вы можете в ответ отправить, документ, картинку, видео, ещё много, чего, или [просто сообщение](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage).

Я пока такой простенький метод написал для вызова методов API Telegram:

```
private function callApi( $method, $params) {
    $url = sprintf(
        "https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/%s",
        Config::get('telegram.token'),
        $method
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST                => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 10,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array( 'Accept-Language: ru,en-us'),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $params,

    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return json_decode( $response);
}
```

Например, уже получив сообщение `$data`, можно на него ответить примерно так:

```
$this->callApi( 'sendMessage', array(
        'chat_id'               => $data->message->chat->id,
        'text'                  => "Здесь сообщение от нашего бота",
        //  'reply_to_message_id'   => $data->message->message_id,
));
```

Comment: Здесь,я так понимаю,имя бота?"https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/%s",вместо процентов?

Comment: @zkolya нет. Там будет токен и название метода. [Ваш лучший друг](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) по php.

А насчё выполнения запросов к апи Телеграма – [тут](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests).

Answer (score 3):

Начни с отправки самого POST запроса через браузер, пойми как работает это:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<токен бота>/sendMessage?chat_id=<айди чата, куда хочешь отправить>&text=<text>
```

затем разложи это на переменные в коде и отправляй.
вот рабочий код, вставь только токен бота:

```
<?php
/**
 * Telegram Bot access token и URL.
 */
$access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $access_token;

/**
 * Задаём основные переменные.
 */
$output = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$chat_id = $output['message']['chat']['id'];
$first_name = $output['message']['chat']['first_name'];
$message = $output['message']['text'];
switch($message) {
case '/test':
sendMessage($chat_id, "HELLO");
break;
}
function sendMessage($chat_id, $message) {
  file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=' . urlencode($message));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Отличное API у них.

```
// прочитываем входящую инфо
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");

// принимаем JSON строку и преобразуем ее в переменную PHP
$update = json_decode($content, true);

//получаем ID чата
$chatID = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$uID = $update["message"]["from"]["username"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот это [PHP Wrapper and Drupal module using Telegram CLI](https://github.com/josereyero/telegram/blob/master/script/send.php). Обертка PHP для Телеграма для командной строки

Comment: Пожалуйста, не публикуйте ответы, состоящие только из одной ссылки. Приведите пример кода, а ссылку добавьте в материалы. Часто ссылки становятся битыми и в таком случае ценность вашего ответа будет стремиться к нулю.

Answer (score -1):

Смотрите akalongman/php-telegram-bot

https://github.com/akalongman/php-telegram-bot

Comment: Пожалуйста, не публикуйте ответы, состоящие только из одной ссылки. Приведите пример кода, а ссылку добавьте в материалы. Часто ссылки становятся битыми и в таком случае ценность вашего ответа будет стремиться к нулю.