# Не работает скрипт PHP для отправки массива данных в Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть форма на сайте и PHP скрипт которому передаються данные для отправки в Telegram. При нажатии на Submit переходит на скрипт но ничего не происходит.
Собственно сам скрипт:

```
<?php
if($_POST['btn'] && !empty($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
$token = "000000:abcdefg..."; // тут указываем токен
$chat_id = 0123456; // а тут id чата
$name = $_POST['name']; // имя
$email = $_POST['email']; // мыло
$message = $_POST['message']; // сообщение
$text = "Пришёл новый отзыв!!!\n\nИмя: ".$name."\nE-mail: ".$email."\nСообщние: ".$message; // собираем всё в единую строку
/* создаем массив данных для отправки запроса */
$params = array(
'chat_id' => $chat_id,
'text' => $text
);
$url = "http://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?".http_build_query($params); // строка с данными
file_get_contents($url); // отправляем данные в телеграм
}
?>
```

Comment: Вероятно дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448750/Отправка-письма-в-telegram @Назар - учитесь пользоваться поиском во всех его проявлениях.

Comment: Но меня интересует именно мой код, а не чужаю реализация.

Comment: Выведите значения $_POST при заходе в данный код.

Comment: и заодно выведите результат запроса

Comment: В ответ получаю:https://api.telegram.org/bot0123456:abcdefg/sendMessage?chat_id=0123456&text=%CF%F0%E8%F8%B8%EB+%ED%EE%E2%FB%E9+%EE%F2%E7%FB%E2%21%21%21%0A%0A%C8%EC%FF%3A+Nazar%0AE-mail%3A+test%40mail.com%0A%D1%EE%EE%E1%F9%ED%E8%E5%3A+Hello+world%21 Telegram ругаеться на кодировку.

Comment: По этой ссылке всё что мы видим это ошибка 401 Unauthorized, связанная с тем что вы передаете неправильный токен. При чем здесь кодировка? Вы читали документацию Телеграма и понимаете что нужно получить ключ бота чтобы иметь возможность слать сообщения на различные каналы ОТ ИМЕНИ этого бота?

Comment: Я просто здесь убрал реальний токен в связи безопасностю. А получаю ответ такой: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message text must be encoded in UTF-8"}

Comment: На HTML форме указал accept-charset="utf-8", в РНР также header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); Но все равно пока вижу %CF%F0%E8%F8%

Comment: Вместо того,чтобы копипастить код в комментарии, дополняйте ответ ;-)

Comment: А в какой кодировке сам файл, тот что выше?

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь! Проблема крылась в строке "$text = "Пришёл новый отзыв!!!" Написал текст на английском и заработало. Буду благодарен кто подскажет как конвертировать строку $text в utf-8.

Comment: @Nazar, для этого нужно файл сохранять в кодировке UTF-8